# Configure doc on ubuntu from .tex and install files

Tags: bash, latex, documentation

I am using a simulation software named Version5 and using it successfully. But I can not configure the doc of it. The docs are in a different directory as mentioned by the readme file.

The directory has some tex and image files and a file named install. In the readme file it says

> "# To configure the doc
> '''cd ~/Version5/doc/IGE335
> ./install'''
> "

I ran that command on that directory and the output is

```
bash: ./install: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have tried setting execution permission from properties but nothing changed.

In the readme file it says to view the output pdf by `gv` command.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: `bash: ./install: /bin/csh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory'` so do you have a C shell (package `tcsh` or `csh`) installed on your system?

Comment: No it was not. Installed it and it worked. Thank you.